Torture room with heated operating room table
I only remember one scene and it had two guys strapped to individual metal tables that look like something from a morgue.  The room was made up like an operating room but was dank and dark.  The disfigured bad guy had one of the tables rigged to heat up and one of the guys is  burned to the table; when he finally tries to get up it rips his skin.  If I remember right the house was in the middle of the woods.  Was on IFC or sundance channel but can't remember the name.

Looks like a good watch for slasher fan like me. Anyways little similar scenes are there in Saw and other franchises but doesn't remember to seen exact this scene.

Do you remember the actors? Were they from Asia (esp. Japan?) or more likely some western country (like the US or Europe)?

See if this fits: Dante Tomaselli's Torture Chamber from 2012 about a disfigured boy who tortures people with the help of local children in a mansion's dungeon. One of the medieval torture devices is a metal slab called the Stove which burns people as you've described; you can see people strapped to it in this trailer (and also the mansion, which seems to be near the woods).

The movie you're looking for is indeed 2009's Shadow:

One guy is slowly cooked on the table and David’s eye is swapped out for a glass replacement but, when the maniac breaks for lunch, he manages to squirm free and release his fellow captives. They soon run into the loon again while David searches for Angeline.

Trailer.
